# can use the with other

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I would like to understand the role of using `the` with `other`.

For example,

> Each row of matrix A contains only three numbers. For example, the entries of the first row are the numbers from 1:3, while the entries of the second row are 4:6, and so on for **the other rows**.

Does `the` is correct here, or should be removed?

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the definite article makes the sentence sound better because you are referring to something specific.

---

But while ***the*** *other rows* sounds more natural than just *other rows*, there are several alternatives that could also be used:

> . . . and so on for ***the*** *other* rows.
>    . . . and so on for ***the*** *remaining* rows.
>    . . . and so on for ***all*** *other* rows.
>    . . . and so on for ***every*** *other* row.
>    . . . and so on for ***the*** *rest*.

Note that in each case, something specific is being mentioned.

---

You could also simply finish the sentence in a simpler form:

> . . . and so on.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: "the other rows". This is preferred. You are not discussing any random matrix. Rather, it's "matrix A", a specific defined matrix which has a finite and definite number of rows.

Option 2: "other rows". This sounds vague and indefinite. If the matrix were going to have an undefined, unknown, ever-changing number of rows (which is the case with some matrices) then maybe this would be alright.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. This is helpful, not only for my case but for other cases.